# Crash when receiving call while playing audio

Tags: iphone, background, internet-radio

I am working on an online radio and it works fine, but gets problem  when user received a call. When call finishes I start the radio automatically, by using `AVAudioSessionDelegate`.

Now radio is playing and if user open the app (moving it to foreground) and press that stop/play button again my app goes crashes. I might know the reason, the reason may be due to threading. But I am unable to handle this (I can't put the code, it is huge and private).

Comment: And if the solution is private too?

Comment: Ok, What is the crash type (Exception type) ?

Comment: @Jhaliya -- That is on device.... how to check the exception type on simulator

Comment: even if it's crashing in device, you could get the crash type (Exception type) by Crash report ...

Comment: try to always put a description of the actual problem in your question title. I've fixed this question, but bear in mind in future.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent crash when your app goes in background and comes in foreground, call the pause button of radio app in background and releases threads. when user touches the play button it it will start threading. Try it,hopes it may work for you.